# MVC4 Deriving a Custom ExtendedMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, customization

I wish to

1. Derive a custom provider like so:

MySimpleMembershipProvider : ExtendedMembershipProvider

1. Override all required members
2. Register MySimpleMembershipProvider in Web.Config so that I can use WebSecurity class as used in the MVC4 template internet web projects

I cannot see how step 3 is accomplished. A beer for anyone who can show me the light.

Answer (score 1):

Register a membership provider in Web.config like this

```
 <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" 
            type="CustomMembership.Models.CustomMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="AppDb"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
            enablePasswordReset="true"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
            requiresUniqueEmail="false"
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
            minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
            passwordAttemptWindow="10"
            applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
```

See [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers) for more details

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Not sure this works for the new SimpleMembershipProvider. Have you used this with the new membership pattern in MVC4?